# Clicking table view cell opens maps with route

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an application with tableView that is in my TableViewController.
I am trying to make it so when user clicks on a cell, it gives them directions to location specified in the code. Right now in order to test it though, I have only added NSLog to it.

I have NSArray in viewDidLoad named tableData that includes all the location names. Those are outputting correctly into the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [mainDelegate.distances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is at the code below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1") {
        NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
    }
}
```

The cell. in if statement gives an error "Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'" and I can't figure what is wrong.

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you should use the underlying data source (tableData) just like you are in cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of using the cell's view objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't know about "cell", since it declared inside another scoop (cellForRowAtIndexPath)

You need to do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know it had to be declared in both functions separately.

Answer (score 0):

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, the variable `cell` is not declared. It is not the same as the cell variable in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method which has a cell variable.

To get a reference to the cell, you could do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1") {
        NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1") {
            NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
        }
    }
```

cell is nothing, is not declared anywhere.

If you want to get the cell that was pressed, use this:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1") {
        NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the cell variable inside that method. Thats why you are getting this error.

Replace:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1") {
        NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
    }
}
```

With:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[cell.textLabel.text] isEqualToString:@"Location 1") {
        NSLog(@"Location 1 clicked");
    }
}
```